# firebase - javascript object returning undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase set up. here is the structure:

[image]

I am having trouble getting the 'newNroomID' value (that is a6QVH, a7LTN etc..).
this value will be use to compare with the other variable value.

I know that in javascript, to access the value of the object it can be done like this:

```
var card = { king : 'spade', jack: 'diamond', queen: 'heart' }
card.jack = 'diamond'
```

but it seems different story when it comes with the firebase or surely enough i am missing something. Here is my code.

```
var pokerRoomsJoin = firebase.database().ref(); // this is how i set it up this block of code is for reading the data only
pokerRoomsJoin.on('value', function(data){
    var rID = data.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(rID);
    var callSet = false;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var indexOfKeys = keys[i];
        var roomMatching = rID[indexOfKeys];
        var matchID = roomMatching.newNroomID; // this does not work alwaus give me undefined
        console.log('this return :' + matchID + ' WHY!')
        console.log(roomMatching)
        if(matchID == 'ffe12'){ // 'ffe12' is actually a dynamic value from a paramiter
            callSet = true;
        }
    }
})
```

and here is the result of the console log:

[image]

strangely i am able to access it like this

```
var matchID = roomMatching.newNroomID // it return a6QVH and a7LTN  one at a time inside the loop
```

only if i set up the ref to :

```
var pokerRoomsJoin = firebase.database().ref('room-' + roomId);
```

I've tried searching but seems different from the structure i have . am I having bad data structure? Save me from this misery , thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let us see the code inside for loop line by line,

```
1.    var indexOfKeys = keys[i];
```

now **indexOfKeys** will hold the key ***room-id***

```
2.    var roomMatching = rID[indexOfKeys];
```

here **roomMatching** will hold the object

```
{ 'firebasePushId': { newDealerName: 'b',
                  ...,
               }
}
```

Now

```
3.     var matchID = roomMatching.newNroomID;
```

> This of-course will be **undefined** because roomMatching has only one
>   property , **firebasePushId**.

To access newNroomID , you have to do something like this,

```
matchID = roomMatching.firebasePushKey.newNroomID .
```

One way to get firebasePushKeys will be using **Object.keys(roomMatching)**.